# Tree builder and printing nodes in a hierarchy

Tags: python, tree

Is there a better was to print a tree? I am doing the following. I am building a tree with the following code. What mistake am I really doing? it is giving the following error

```
      63         ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.label)+"\n"          
      64         for child in self.children:     
 ---> 65             ret += child.__str__(level+1)          
      66         return ret          
      67 

TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1
```

Code attached below

```
from collections import Counter
from sets import Set

class treenode:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.label = values
        self.children = {}

    def __str__(self, level=0):
        ret = "\t"*level+repr(self.label)+"\n"
        for child in self.children:
            ret += child.__str__(level+1)
        return ret

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<tree node representation>'

def build_tree(featurerange, featureid, counts):
    if len(sorted(counts)) > 1:
        featuresLeft = featurerange - Set([featureid])
        if not featuresLeft:
            rootnode.children[v] = treenode(counts.most_common(1)[0][0])
        else:
            rootnode.children[v] = build_tree(featuresLeft)
    else:
        rootnode.children[v] = treenode(counts.most_common(1)[0][0])

    return rootnode

featurerange = set([0, 1])
featureid = 1
counts = Counter({'-': 49, '+': 45})  

tree = build_tree(featurerange, featureid, counts)
str(tree)
print tree
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample `featurerange`, `featureid` and `counts` input?

Comment: Why are you using `Set()` (presumably imported from the [deprecated `sets` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) rather than the built-in type?

Comment: Presumably `counts` is a `collections.Counter()` instance?

Comment: yes counts is a collections.Counter()

Comment: Can you provided us with a minimal sample of inputs to reproduce the problems? You'll need to add what imports you are using too.

Comment: featurerange = set([0, 1])
featureid = 1
counts = Counter({'-': 49, '+': 45})

Comment: By the checkmark on my post I take it that you solved the issue now. I've added those values to your question, but note that because `v` is a global used by `build_tree` we still cannot fully reprouce your issue.

Comment: Also, you cannot mix `Set()` and `set()` objects like you are doing. Which one is it, `set()` or `Set()`?

Comment: And I note that you are using `build_tree()` without the required 3 arguments inside `buildtree` itself, so even with your sample input corrected to use `Set()`, the code throws an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `children` to default to an empty dictionary:

```
def __init__(self, values, children = {}):
```

shared between instances. You then proceed to **replace** the same key over and over again with:

```
rootnode.children[v] = treenode(counts.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

where `v` is a global; you haven't shared it in your question, so I don't know what kind of object that is.

Looping over `self.children` then loops over the **keys** of the dictionary:

```
for child in self.children:
```

`child` is then **not** a `treenode` instance, so the `__str__` method doesn't take extra arguments. It is instead that one `v` value, but it clearly does not implement a `object.__str__` method that takes extra arguments.

Perhaps you wanted to make `children` a list instead? In any case, there are several issues in your code that you need to address:

- You are using a mutable default argument here, you are creating **one** dictionary and all your instances share it. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for why you want to avoid that. Use:

  ```
  def __init__(self, values, children=None):
      if children is None:
          children = {}
  ```
- You appear to be using a `v` global in `build_tree()`; did you really need to use a dictionary and *one* key in that dictionary? Shouldn't `children` be a sequence or collection instead? If so, use `list.append()` or `set.add()` grow the collection of children.
- You appear to be using the [deprecated `sets.Set()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html); use the [built-in `set()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead.

The approach itself, **provided you actually loop over a collection of `treenode` objects**, works just fine. You could loop over the values of the dictionary, perhaps:

```
for child in self.children.values():
```

Comment: I have now changed the definition of the tree, still I am getting the same error.